# Generating Binary Inputs in C

Tags: c, binary, truthtable

Essentially, I have a program that has eight variables. I'm attempting to check every combination of truth values for these eight variables, and so I need a truth table using 0s and 1s that demonstrate every combination of them. These inputs will be read into the program.

It should look something like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

And so on...

How would I accomplish this in C?
I've opened up a file for writing, but I'm not sure how to... Logically do this.

Comment: If you imagine that the individual bits are binary digits of a number, can you spot a pattern?

Comment: @KalîlÁrmstrøng Oh well. I thought you just couldn't implement it... I didn't realize you didn't know these are just the natural numbers in binary. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Convert every decimal number till 2^8, into corresponding binary number...
and you have the required pattern.....

Answer (score 1):

Two loops and the character `'0'` are more than enough...

```
FILE *f = fopen("truth.txt", "w"); // we'll alter the truth...
assert(f != NULL);

unsigned i;
int j;
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        fprintf(f, "%c ", '0' + ((i >> (7 - j)) & 1));
    }
    fprintf(f, "\n");
}

fclose(f);
```